# Trouble initializing a <Position> variable in Flutter LateInitializationError: Field '____ ' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

newbie to Flutter.  My code runs but encounters a

> The following LateError was thrown building
> FutureBuilder(dirty, state:
> _FutureBuilderState#e1a6f):
> LateInitializationError: Field 'initialPosition' has not been
> initialized.

The code is to set up a GoogleMap widget that takes initial position from the device. I get the red screen with that error, but after a few seconds the coordinates gets received and proceeds as normal and displays the map and position correctly.
Tried **future** as well but but I get other errors.  Is it supposed to be under the FutureBuilder? In a wrapper.dart or my main.dart?

home.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:something/services/auth.dart';
import 'screens/map.dart';
import 'package:something/services/geolocator_service.dart';

class LakoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override


  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<LakoApp> {

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  final _geolocatorService = GeolocatorService();
  late var initialPosition;

  // @override


  Future getInitialPosition <Position>() async {
    initialPosition = await _geolocatorService.getInitialLocation();
    return initialPosition;
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: FittedBox(
            child: Text('Something something'),
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
           // irrelevant code
           // .....
           
          
        ],
        body:

        FutureBuilder(

            future: getInitialPosition(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
               return Map(initialPosition);
   
            }
        )
    );
  }  
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Future Builders are built even before getting the data. So, you should check whether it has data.

```dart
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Map(initialPosition); //Or snapshot.data.
              }else{
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
```

There are other problems here. I will show some further code to improve your own code.

Your method returns a Future of any type receiving a generic parameter called Position. I think you want to use a data type called position for that you need to move `<Position>` here as right now the way you are writing it is useless for your specific example.

```dart
Future<Position> getInitialPosition () async {
    initialPosition = await _geolocatorService.getInitialLocation();
    return initialPosition;
  }
```

The FutureBuilder can be like this.

```dart
FutureBuilder<Position>(
            future: getInitialPosition(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Map(snapshot.data);
              }else{
                return CircularProgressIndicator(); 
                //Display loading, you may adapt this widget to your interface or use some state management solution
              }
            }
        )
```

Comment: i trying this out but they created more errors. But I'm sure it has data, when I  print(snapshot.data) coordinates appear.

Comment: managed to fix the errors except this in the builder: (context, snapshot) parameter. Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Widget' doesn't allow null.

Comment: It needs to return a widget like `CircularPorgressIndicator` or `SizedBox` as it needs to build something

Answer (score 1):

Edited the code according to suggestions: got rid of the method and variable, because its redundant

```
body: FutureBuilder <Position> (
        future: _geolocatorService.getInitialLocation(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Map(snapshot.data!);
          }else {
            return Loading();
```